# Property 'brews' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

Tags: angular

When I try to run my project I get this error, I tried to set strictPropertyInitialization false in angularCompilerOptions but it doesn´t work also I tried to set ! instead brews
[image]

```
import { HttpService } from '../http.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.scss']
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

   brews: Object; 

  constructor(private _http: HttpService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._http.getBeer().subscribe(data  => {
      this.brews = data
      console.log(this.brews);
    });
  }

}
```

```
<h1>Breweries</h1>

<ul *ngIf="brews">
  <li *ngFor="let brew of brews">
    <p class="name">{{ brew.name }}</p>
    <p class="country">{{ brew.country }}</p>
    <a class="site" href="{{ brew.website_url }}">site</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

We're facing the same error too. Maybe it is caused by the different version of Angular.

Change the ListComponent class to the following:

```
brews: Array<any> = [];

  constructor( private _http:HttpService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._http.getBeer().subscribe(data => {
      this.brews = data as Array<Object>;
      console.log(this.brews);
    });
  }
```

This answer credited to ram64 on youtube comment.

Answer (score 0):

`brews: Object;` is saying that `brews` must always be set and always be an `Object`.  But this cannot possibly be the case if it has no default value and isn't set in the constructor.  There will be a moment where `brews` has no value before it is eventually set through your `subscribe` callback.

You need to allow for `brews` to possibly be `undefined`.  `brews?: Object;` should do it.  Or `brews: Object | undefined = undefined;` if you want to be more explicit.

Comment: if I do that I got this error : "Type 'Object' is not assignable"

Comment: One of the other errors in your screenshot is telling you that `Object` is not a good type to use.  It is the object constructor.  You probably meant to use the lowercase `object`.  But it is better if you can use a type for that specific object.